# Uniqueness of deconvolution after convolution?

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, convolution, queueing-theory

I have the following question and I'd greatly appreciate any help!

Basically, I have an arbitrary probability distribution with pdf $f(x)$, we can assume it's continuous with support on $[0,\infty]$

Denote $g(x)$ as pdf of an exponential random variable with fixed, known rate $\lambda$, and $h(x) = f(x) * g(x)$ where $*$ is convolution.

My question is, does $h(x)$ uniquely determine $f(x)$? i.e. if I "deconvolve" $h(x)$ with an exponential random variable, do I recover $f(x)$ uniquely?

First time posting here. Hope my question makes sense and is clear enough.

Comment: While Iosif's solution works for general convolution kernels, in this particular case there is a simpler solution: $\lambda^{-1} e^{\lambda x} h(x)$ turns out to be the integral of $e^{\lambda x} f(x)$, and hence $f(x) = \lambda^{-1} e^{-\lambda x} (e^{\lambda x} h(x))'$.

Comment: Interesting! Thank you Mateusz!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes. Let $\hat p$ denote the characteristic function of a pdf $p$, so that
$$\hat p(t)=\int_{\mathbb R}e^{itx}p(x)\,dx$$
for real $t$. Then $\hat h=\hat f\,\hat g$ and
$$\hat g(t)=\frac1{1-it/\lambda}$$
for real $t$, so that
$$\hat f(t)=\hat h(t)/\hat g(t)=\hat h(t)(1-it/\lambda)$$
for real $t$. [Inverting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Inversion_formulae) now the characteristic function $\hat f$, we get $f$.

Comment: Thanks a lot Iosif! I was thinking the similar via mgf but realized mgf does not necessarily exist. This is greatly helpful. Thanks again!